# Cannot integrate Eclipse EE with Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have successfully setup Tomcat on my PC (Windows) and it works with sample hello world servlet.  I am using Tomcat native (which I believe has its own inbuilt web server).

I have downloaded and installed Eclipse Java EE and have created a simple servlet.

In Preferences I have added the Tomcat Server and path to installation directory:
D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0.

I also added the servlet-api.jar file from the Tomcat download to the project Java Build Path as an external JAR.

Error:
Problem occurred 'Launching Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use.  The server may already be running...

The server is already running but if I stop the service and re-run get same error.  If Tomcat is running when I start to Run in Eclipse then it stops Tomcat???

In the Eclipse address bar windows I have
_http://localhost:8080/MyLittleDynamicWebProject/servlet/MyFirstServlet.MyFirstServlet

and I see a view of web page
HTTP Status 404 - requested resource is not available.

Could it be a problem Eclipse creating the necessary folder structure?

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem using eclipse when running Tomcat as a service.  I saw on youtube that tomcat integrated with eclipse was being started as a command line application.  So I uninstalled the Tomcat which had been installed on my Windows machine using an installer.  I deleted my previous eclipse workspace folder.

Then followed these steps.

1. Create a top level folder (eg java_web_programming).
2. Copy eclipse download into a folder called eclipse under this top level folder.
3. At same level copied tomcat 7 download.
4. Started eclipse in servers tab created new server, pointing to /tomcat-7 folder (under java_web_programming).

Now everything works.

Just goes to show that just doing things the same old way you used to do them... doesn't always work.